# State can't access props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add `selectedUserIds` in state constructor by using `userListIds` from props. However, it seems that at the time when constructor is executed the value in props is not set yet thus I am getting null.

However, when I am printing `this.props.userListIds` at the beginning of the render it shows just fine. Problem is somewhere else. What might be the solution? Here is the code:

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state: State, props: OwnProps): PropsFromState => ({
      userList: getCompanyTeamListSelector(state),
      userListIds: state.ddls.companyUsers.map(element => Number(element.id))
    });


@connect(mapStateToProps)
export default class EmailModal extends React.Component<OwnProps & Partial<PropsFromDispatch> & Partial<PropsFromState>, OwnState> {
  constructor(props: OwnProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      valueSelected: true, selectedUserIds: this.props.userListIds // HERE
    }}
```

Comment: Just use `props` in the constructor, not `this.props`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing React wrong. If the value can be accessed in the props, the value should stay in the props. Duplicating the data between the props and the state can lead to useless component re-rendering, and most importantly many bugs, especially when plugging libraries like React-Redux that will extensively manipulate the props.

Oh, and use `props` in the constructor, not `this.props`.

Comment: Props are immutable and I need this value to be dynamic. Thanks, will try this out

Comment: Ok, that works since it's now two different variables that don't need to be in sync

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to initialize some state from a prop value

Comment: @MatthewHerbst looking at the code it appeared that `userListIds` needed to be identical in the state and in the props, which was later clarified as false by the OP, but my remark on **duplicating** the data remains (**initializing** data, however, is indeed perfectly reasonable)

Comment: The problem is that the userListIds is in PropsFromState and not in OwnProps so I can't use props.userListIds. I tried a few solutions, but nothing worked. What's the right solution for this one?

Comment: Found a way to use props instead of this.props but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Props is external data resource for a React component, so you should always assume that props data is not reliable, and take care of empty/undefined props in your component.

Given constructor function is executed before the first rendering in component lifecycle, it's possible that during the execution of constructor function, `props.userListIds` can be empty, and at `render`, it's retrieved and ready to be used. If you really want to store `userListIds` in local state, you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update local state:

```
public static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: IProps, prevState: IState) {
  return (nextProps.userListIds != prevState.selectedUserIds) ? 
    { selectedUserIds: nextProps.userListIds } :
    null
}
```

But same as other comments here, I am also against the idea of copying props to local state, since you will have 2 separated sources of truth for same piece of data and need to update local state whenever your props changes. You can consider directly using `props.userListIds` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but getDerivedStateFromProps did not work either.